# ServiceStack Overwrites First Row In UserAuth Table When Registering New User

Tags: authorization, servicestack, registration

I'm using the built-in authorization and registration features in ServiceStack (a la Razor Rockstars), and it's really great! But, I'm having a strange issue. Whenever I register a new user, the first row of my UserAuth table (I'm using SqlServer) gets OVERWRITTEN instead of adding a new row. The strange part is that my co-worker was able to successfully register and add a new row to the table from his machine, but ever since then, every new registration overwrites the first row of the table resulting in a lot of frustration.

I have not customized the registration service ( I haven't figured out how, yet) at all. In AppHost.cs:

```
    container.Register<IDbConnectionFactory>(
            new OrmLiteConnectionFactory(ConfigUtils.GetConnectionString("MyDatabase"),
                SqlServerDialect.Provider));

    ...

    Plugins.Add(new AuthFeature(() => new AuthUserSession(),
            new IAuthProvider[] {
                new CustomCredentialsAuthProvider()
            }
        ));

    Plugins.Add(new RegistrationFeature());

    container.Register<IUserAuthRepository>(c =>
            new OrmLiteAuthRepository(c.Resolve<IDbConnectionFactory>()));

    var authRepo = (OrmLiteAuthRepository)container.Resolve<IUserAuthRepository>();
    authRepo.CreateMissingTables();
```

What I have done in my CustomCredentialsAuthProvider is very basic:

```
    public override bool TryAuthenticate(ServiceStack.ServiceInterface.IServiceBase authService, string userName, string password)
    {
        //Add here your custom auth logic (database calls etc)
        //Return true if credentials are valid, otherwise false

        //Call the base class if needed
        return base.TryAuthenticate(authService, userName, password);
    }

    public override void OnAuthenticated(IServiceBase authService, IAuthSession session, IOAuthTokens tokens, Dictionary<string, string> authInfo)
    {   
        //Fill the IAuthSession with data which you want to retrieve in the app eg:
        //session.FirstName = "some_firstname_from_db";


        //base.OnAuthenticated(authService, session, tokens, authInfo);

        //Important: You need to save the session!
        authService.SaveSession(session, SessionExpiry);

    }
```

The form code I'm using was working fine for the first and second registrations. But, every registration after that overwrites the first row in the table:

```
    <form action='@Url.Content("~/register")' method='POST'>
        <fieldset>
            <legend>Create New Account</legend>
          <input type='hidden' name='Continue' value='@Url.Content("~/admin/users")' />
            <dl>
                <dt>User Name:</dt>
                <dd><input type='text' name='UserName' /></dd>
                <dt>Email:</dt>
                <dd><input type='text' name='Email' /></dd>
                <dt>Password:</dt>
                <dd><input type='password' name='Password' /></dd>
            </dl>             
            <input type='submit' value='Create' />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```